# Unable to install Kivy v1.10.0 with Python 3.6.0

Tags: python, installation, kivy, python-3.6

I am facing problems installing Kivy (`v1.10.0`) with Python `3.6.0`. But it is working completely fine with Python `2.7.12`, and Python `3.5.2`. I want to work with Python `3.6.0`.

My System: `Ubuntu 16.04 64-Bit`

Python 2.7.12:

```
>>> import kivy
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/nvs/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-08-31_5.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Python 3.5.2

```
>>> import kivy
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/nvs/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-08-31_6.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Python 3.6.0:

```
>>> import kivy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

I have followed steps for stable install from [here](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-kubuntu-xubuntu-lubuntu-saucy-and-above).

I want to know how to make work Kivy with Python `3.6.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install it? i have it working here in a virtualenv

```
gabriel@gryphon:/tmp> virtualenv -p python3.6 .testvenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /tmp/.testvenv/bin/python3.6
Also creating executable in /tmp/.testvenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
```

(disregard the fact that i use activate.fish, because i use the fish shell, use the correct activate for your shell)

```
gabriel@gryphon:/tmp> . .testvenv/bin/activate.fish
```

install cython

```
(.testvenv) 11:46:29 02/09/17 1,47.testvenv 0
gabriel@gryphon:/tmp> pip install cython
Collecting cython
  Using cached Cython-0.26.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: cython
Successfully installed cython-0.26.1
```

and finally install kivy

```
gabriel@gryphon:/tmp> pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
  Using cached Kivy-1.10.0.tar.gz
Collecting Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4 (from kivy)
Collecting docutils (from kivy)
  Using cached docutils-0.14-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pygments (from kivy)
  Using cached Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests (from Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
  Using cached requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
  Using cached urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
  Using cached certifi-2017.7.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
  Using cached idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: kivy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for kivy ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/gabriel/.cache/pip/wheels/44/dc/e1/8f36be467f9d8c3b27d172a64a55b887212b86727684ca18e8
Successfully built kivy
Installing collected packages: urllib3, certifi, idna, chardet, requests, Kivy-Garden, docutils, pygments, kivy
Successfully installed Kivy-Garden-0.1.4 certifi-2017.7.27.1 chardet-3.0.4 docutils-0.14 idna-2.6 kivy-1.10.0 pygments-2.2.0 requests-2.18.4 urllib3-1.22
```

testing it

```
gabriel@gryphon:/tmp> python
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 22 2017, 06:17:05) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170321] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import kivy
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/gabriel/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-09-02_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.1 (default, Mar 22 2017, 06:17:05) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170321]
>>>
```

Comment: Hi, can you please look at the answer I just posted? In your answer I see you've used Cython==0.26.1. I tried 0.27 but it failed, so I rolled back to 0.25 as recommended in the Kivy installation page. Could you please point me to how I can check whether Kivy can be used with more recent versions of Cython? Is there a script that runs such a test, or could you guide me how I could do it? We need it for our product, and it will surely help the Kivy community as well. Thanks

Comment: I don't think we have systematic tests with new cython releases, they tend to break things (after all, it's still not 1.0…) so it's not uncommon that we have to fix things. It could be nice to have some CI that is triggered both on new Kivy commits *and* new Cython releases, to know about such issues. not sure where this would be best done, maybe you can drop by #kivy-dev on freenode to discuss it?

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me.
After reading one of the comments [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/), I installed a few more packages to get it to work (not sure if all of them are necessary)

`apt-get install python3.6 idle-python3.6 python3.6-doc python3.6-examples libpython3.6 libpython3.6-stdlib python-clang-3.6 python-lldb-3.6 libpython3.6-dbg python3.6-venv`

Then, I made a new virtualenv and installed specifically Cython==0.25.2:

`mkvirtualenv kivyinstall -p python3.6
workon kivyinstall
pip install Cython==0.25.2
pip install Kivy==1.10.0`

This worked. Using the latest Cython version didn't work for me unfortunately.
I wonder when this will be tested by the Kivy guys. In [Kivy's installation page](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html) it's written that Cython==0.25 is the recommended version but Cython has moved on since then.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and running Eclipse Oxygen 2018. I installed pip
and wanted to run python3.6

(1) sudo pip3.6 install python3.6

(2) sudo apt-get update

(3) sudo pip3.6 install cython

4. sudo pip3.6 install kivy

To test python3.6 from command line terminal

next >>> import cython if no error gonna work in 3.6

next >>> import kivy your golden no error on my system.

So the cool part is now I can use this integrated with eclipse.
Happy Coding hope this helps..